# JFrame Container.add method class reference

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe, jpanel

I stumbled upon a simple PacMan game made by a channel on youtube called "Learn Coding from Scratch". In the code there are 3 class files which are Player, Level1 and Executable. This is the Level1's code;

```
public class Level1 extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("PacMan");
    private ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("images//background.jpeg");
    private Player player = new Player(5, 10, 10, "images//pacman_right.jpg", true, 0); 
    private int speed = 10;

    public Level1() {

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        **window.add(this);**

        window.setSize(940, 627);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
}
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        player.drawPlayer(g);
    }
```

What I don't understand is "window.add(this)". I've never seen JPanel and JFrame examples where you have to reference the current class in the JFrame. You just add buttons, labels etc. with ".add" not the current class? Besides I checked the Oracle documents for Container.add method but basically you can put anything in there, which didn't help me much. Could you guys take a look at this?
Thanks in advance.
P.s. I know Most of the code I posted is redundant but someone will ask for the whole code anyways :)

Comment: *"channel on youtube called "Learn Coding from Scratch""* Unfortunately these folks are not competent to write code, let alone make videos tutoring people about writing code. There are a number of mistakes or non-robust approaches even in the short code example above. Instead go through the [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) trail of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know these sources are quite often misleading but I'm trying to sponge all the information out there. I'm gonna check out the tutorial you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Level1 extends JPanel`. That means that it is a `JPanel`. The object named `window` is a JFrame. By writing

> window.add(this);

inside `Level1`'s constructor, you add `this` **JPanel** into the frame.

You have never seen it before because the most common practice is to `extends` a JFrame, and then create panels and add them like:
`this.add(myPanel); //this refers to a frame, mypanel refers to a JPanel`

In order to make it more clear, take a look at the most common practice and compare with yours:

```
public class PacmanFrame extends JFrame {
    public PacmanFrame() {
        //this refers to our class, extending JFrame
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        this.add(myPanel);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"the most common practice"* That may or may not be true in general, but in this specific instance, there is a **reason** to extend `JPanel`, but none to extend `JFrame`.

Comment: @Andrew Thomson I guess you are right. I just had it in my mind as "the most common practice" because most examples follows it. I was referring to examples. But yeah, i have no idea if it is common or not. I just said what i have seen from examples (around SO). Thanks for mentioning this.